# how to create each word of input to start a new line

Tags: c, eof, getchar, putchar

Hey i am trying to print each word on a new line. My EOF is also not working and was wondering why this is. i have made it to scan for a space and then print new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
        putchar(ch);

int nextChar;
    nextChar = getchar();
    while (nextChar != '\n' && nextChar != EOF);
    {
        if (ch== ' ')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        {
            ch = getchar();
        }
        printf("\n");

        {
            scanf("%lc",&nextChar);
            printf("%c",nextChar);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

```js
just for example input: Stackoverflow is great
output:
Stackoverflow
is
great
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem description. How is it not working?

Comment: Hi J.K and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an example of the input you use, the output you get, and what output you had expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should REALLY start enabling compiler warnings. They can help you find many bugs. Look here when I compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

```
$ gcc ba.c -Wall -Wextra
ba.c: In function ‘main’:
ba.c:13:5: warning: this ‘while’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     while (nextChar != '\n' && nextChar != EOF);
     ^~~~~
ba.c:14:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘while’
     {
     ^
```

Remove the `;` after the while loop.

But there are other problems too. As you can see from when I corrected the indentation for you, the `return 0` statement is inside the while loop. I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: thankyou but im still not sure how to get the output correct